# what is the need of ng-hide directive, we could have done that with ng-show by giving falsy value only

Tags: angularjs

What is the need of **`ng-hide`** directive,

We could have done that with **`ng-show`** by giving ***false*** value only?

Comment: as pointed they simply remove/add `css` respectively

Answer (score 0):

The **[ng-hide](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHide)** and [**ng-show**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow) directives are analog to each other and only differentiate each other in the ways you need to implement the logic for them to work.

`ng-hide` hides the item when the condition asked is `true` and `ng-show` show the item when the condition asked is `true` as well.

This only adds a *class* called `ng-hide` that puts a *css* attribute of `display: none !important` and `ng-show` removes that attribute.

But something important comes along with something called **[ng-if](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf)**. `ng-if` removes entirely from the DOM the element if the condition is true, so instead of adding a class that hides the element, `ng-if` removes it completely.

Hope it helps.